# Column type NONE in sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have sqlite database that I using it with Android platform.

I have created the table in run-time. My SQL was:

```
CREATE TABLE funcs ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, func_name TEXT, param NONE)
```

Each row in this table present function call in my program. And the parameter change it type for each row.

And also, I have been created class that preset one row of the table

```
class FunctionDB
{
    private ContentValues mContentValues;

    public FunctionDB(Cursor cursor)
    {
        DatabaseUtils.cursorRowToContentValues(cursor, this.mContentValues);
    }

    public int getID()
    {
        return this.mContentValues.getAsInteger("id");
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.mContentValues.getAsString("func_name");
    }

    public ??? getParam()
    {
        return this.mContentValues.getAs???("param");
    }

}
```

I want that this class be general function type.
Thats means, that I want by checking the name of the function, determine what is the type of the `param` column.

How can I receive the generic type of the `param` column in my code?

Comment: The Cursor class already does this work for you... However you can always use the generic [`ContentValues#get()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html#get%28java.lang.String%29) method and convert the Object into whatever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html), the generic way of reading some values is to use `get`, which returns an `Object`.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the fast answer!
How can I set this column in code?

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a clean way of doing this.

```
typeof(columnName)
```

will return the data type as String.

```
String dataType = this.typeof("param");

if (dataType.equalsIgnoreCase("TEXT"){

if (dataType.equalsIgnoreCase("INTEGER"){

...
```